# Как работает тип Pop

Tags: typescript

```
type Pop<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer I, infer _] ? I : never
```

Это [рекомендованное](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/37) решение для типа `Pop` в [type-challenge](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges).

Так же работающие решения:

```
type Pop<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer U, ...[unknown]] 
  ? U 
  : never

type Pop<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer U, unknown] 
  ? U 
  : never
```

Если нам надо удалить больше типов, то мы просто добавляем:

```
type Pop<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer U, ...[unknown, unknown]] 
  ? U 
  : never

Pop<[1,2,3,4,5]> // [1,2,3]
```

Если написать тоже самое без условного типа, получается обычный *merge*:

```
type Merge<T extends any[], K extends any[]>  = [...T, ...K]

type m = Merge<[1,2,3], [1,unknown,unknown]>
//   ^? [1,2,3,1,unknown,unknown]
```

Как это работает?

Comment: непонятно что именно ты хочешь в ответе увидеть. Логика вроде бы очевидна - переданный тип массива сопоставляется с шаблоном в extends и возвращается результат

Comment: @Grundy Вашими комментариями можно комментировать любые вопросы или ответы. **Логика вроде бы очевидна** - нет, не очевидна. Почему в условном типе с ключевым словом `infer` пропадают последние два типа, а без него(не в условном типе) происходит слияние?

Comment: потому что в условном типе ты возвращаешь то, что вернул `infer` - а именно часть спереди, а без условном типе ты конструируешь тип из двух массивов

Comment: @Grundy потому что в условном типе ты возвращаешь то, что вернул `infer` -  это понятно. Не понятно почему там на элемент меньше, в случае `T extends [...infer I, infer _] ? I : never`?

Comment: Потому что, один infer сопоставляет с последним элементом, а все предыдущие сопоставляются с `I`

Comment: @Grundy один - это первый?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133583/discussion-between------and-grundy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип `Pop`

```
type Pop<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer I, infer _] ? I : never
```

Принцип работы

- тип `I` выводится автоматически из контекста на основе типа `T`;
- тип `_` выводится автоматически из контекста на основе типа `T`;
- `T extends [...infer I, infer _]` - в квадратных скобках - деструктуризация.
- Если левая часть может быть сопоставлена правой возвращаем урезанный кортеж типов, в противном случае `never`.

Пример:

```
Pop<[1,2,3]> // [1,2]
```

Разбор:

- В результате деструктуризации, в типе `I` будет `[1,2]`, а в типе `_` будет `3`;
- Получаем условный тип: `[1,2,3] extends [1,2,3] ? [1,2] : never`, где `1,2` -> `...[1,2]` -> `...infer I`;
- Так как `[1,2,3]` можно сопоставить с `[1,2,3]`, то возвращаем тип `I`, т.е. `[1,2]`.

Большое спасибо [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy), за детальное объяснение.